# Yup Typescript Union/Intersection Validation

Tags: typescript, yup

For a project I use [yup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup) but I am having problems getting a good type from the schema ... Ideally I'd get a Type that shows when a Property has a certain Value, another property has to be defined!

I built a quick [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-keller-zkws2q?file=/src/index.ts) that shows the problem but I post it here too if you don't want to switch ...

### Schema Definition like this

```
const schema = yup.object({
  contactForm: yup
    .mixed<"phone" | "email">()
    .required()
    .oneOf(["email", "phone"]),
  email: yup.string().when("contactForm", {
    is: "email",
    then: (schema) => schema.required().email(),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.transform(() => undefined)
  }),
  phone: yup.string().when("contactForm", {
    is: "phone",
    then: (schema) => schema.required(),
    otherwise: (schema) => schema.transform(() => undefined)
  })
});
```

### Schema Type

`type Schema = yup.InferType<typeof schema>;`

### What I get:

```
type Schema = {
    contactForm: "email" | "phone";
    email: string | undefined;
    phone: string | undefined;
}
```

Now when I check an Object which has the `contactForm: "email"` TypeScript will still complain that email might be undefined. For small Objects that might be okay, but I have schemas where multiple properties need to be defined when a property has a certain value which makes TypeScript feel kind of useless ...

### What I want

```
type Schema = {contactForm: "email"; email: string} | {contactForm: "phone"; phone: string};
```

Is this not possible with Yup ? If it is possible, how would I need to define the Schema ?

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible currently. You have to write complete Schema in TS.

Comment: Check https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-buck-cv8ple, if this this is what you need

Comment: Hello @gyanroy, Although your solution works, I feel like there is some room for error :( -- I forked your solution and added my own "spin" https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-water-5x8rj6?file=/src/index.ts -- I feel like this way is a tad better, since I can define subschemas and merge them, so there might be a tad more type safety. But! It is still not great, so either I'd need to switch to zod, which has better union/intersection support or just accept the fact that this is not possible